# How do you reset the default "IP Security Policies on Active Directory" back to their factory settings?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ipsec

How do you reset the default "IP Security Policies on Active Directory" back to their factory settings?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're talking about the Default Domain Policy or the Default Domain Controllers Policy You can either compare them to a non-modified GPO in another domain or you can run DCGPOFIX.

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/12/how-to-reset-the-default-domain-group-policy-objects-dcgpofix

**EDIT**

I don't understand what you're saying with your comment. Look at this image. This is from/in the DD GPO:

[image]

Comment: No, I am referring to the Client (Respond Only), Secure Server (Require Security) and Server (Request Security) policy. I don't think they have anything to do with the DD GPO & DDC GPO.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: As I understand it, the policy definitions are global across the domain, and not specific to any one GPO. Only the assignments can vary from one GPO to the next. I removed all the policies from a GPO that I had created and now they are not listed/available in any other policy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found, there is no built-in reset option. What I ended up doing was exporting the default policies from a newly created Active Directory to a file, then importing them into my existing Active Directory.